# Flip data for use in graph upside down with intervals unchanged (exactly as in picture attached)

Tags: matlab, transform, transformation

I am using MATLAB and need to flip data in a graph upside down as in pic below;

[image]

I.e. I have vector A = [1 2 3 4 4 4 3 3 3] (blue line) and I need to transform it *exactly* into B = [4 3 2 1 1 1 2 2 2] (red line). Note that I need the interval of the x- and y-axis to be *unchanged*. I have tried `flipud`, `fliplr`, `flip` and `rot90`, without any success.

Please note that I need to transform the data itself (it is not enough to flip the image upside down).

Stuck for a while, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Questions are not a place to put answers. In this case, that copied the same idea as in the posted answer. Furthermore, a loop is an overkill for this process and the posted answer is meant to be used as it is. (i.e. without the loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematically, it is the following transformation:

```
B = -A + min(A) + max(A);
```